# How can I obtain the .hex of a file

Tags: arduino-yun, compile

I have an Arduino Yún running Openwrt-Yún 1.5.3 (which is the latest version, as I upgraded yesterday), and I am trying to obtain a .hex (compiled sketch), so that I can upload a sketch directly into the Yún. I know about compiled sketches, but there are no build directories in "C:\Documents and Settings\MY_USERNAME\Local Settings\Temp".

Where can I obtain the .hex of any file I have compiled, and how?

Comment: Have you tried enabling verbose compilation?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - Yes: I know what the build is called and its location whilst I upload, but after I have uploaded, nothing.

Comment: Compile the sketch and in log it is shown where the hex is stored. Then you have to copy from there, because its in temporary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in comments, enable verbose compilation and look at the output to find the temporary-directory location. (Click File, Preferences, verbose compilation.)

Note, after you click File, Preferences and the preferences window appears with its half-dozen items, you should also see a note about directly editing preferences in the preferences.txt file.  Edit that file (using a plain-text editor, not a word processor) when the arduino IDE is not running.  Change the line

```
preproc.save_build_files=false
```

to

```
preproc.save_build_files=true
```

so the .hex files in the temporary directory have a better chance of sticking around.

(I'm not able to test this suggestion on an MS-Windows system.  On my Linux system most build files stick around anyway in /tmp/)